# Creating Loops Through Columns in Existing Macro & Calling From Main Macro

Tags: vba, excel

*I have edited my previous post upon improving my code*

Original (messy) code included below for reference.  Carries out the following tasks.

1. Set up conditional formatting in Column B of my table.
2. Format paint that across each of the columns in the table.
3. Filter formatted cells in each column and turn text colour to red.
4. Replace all cells containing red text with '*'.

*Original Code*

```
Sub FabricationClearConDups()
'
' Currently this Sub will highlight all consecutive duplicates in all rows
' then format all duplicates with red text colour.

With Application
.ScreenUpdating = False
.EnableEvents = False
.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
End With

'Select first row (B) and set conditional format.
    Range("Fabrication_Table[Fab01_Vision02.WidthReagentStripMaSideAvg]").Select
        Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=OR(B2=B1,B2=B3)"
        Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority

    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 65535
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False

'Format Paint the formula across all rows in Fab Worksheet
Selection.Copy
    Range("C2").Select
                Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats, Operation:=xlNone, _
                SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    Range("D2").Select
                Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats, Operation:=xlNone, _
                SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    Range("E2").Select
                Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats, Operation:=xlNone, _
                SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    Range("F2").Select
                Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats, Operation:=xlNone, _
                SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    Range("G2").Select
                Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats, Operation:=xlNone, _
                SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    Range("H2").Select
                Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats, Operation:=xlNone, _
                SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    Range("I2").Select
                Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats, Operation:=xlNone, _
                SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    Range("J2").Select
                Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats, Operation:=xlNone, _
                SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    Range("K2").Select
                Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats, Operation:=xlNone, _
                SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    Range("L2").Select
                Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats, Operation:=xlNone, _
                SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    Range("M2").Select
                Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats, Operation:=xlNone, _
                SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    Range("N2").Select
                Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats, Operation:=xlNone, _
                SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    Range("O2").Select
                Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats, Operation:=xlNone, _
                SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    Range("P2").Select
                Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats, Operation:=xlNone, _
                SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    Range("Q2").Select
                Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats, Operation:=xlNone, _
                SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
Application.CutCopyMode = False

'Change actual cell format to Red Text
    Range("Fabrication_Table[Fab01_Vision02.WidthReagentStripMaSideAvg]").Select
        ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Fabrication_Table").Range.AutoFilter Field:=2, _
        Criteria1:=RGB(255, 255, 0), Operator:=xlFilterCellColor
            With Selection.Font
                 .Color = -16776961
                 .TintAndShade = 0
            End With
        ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Fabrication_Table").Range.AutoFilter Field:=2

    Range("Fabrication_Table[Fab01_Vision02.WidthReagentStripOpSideAvg]").Select
        ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Fabrication_Table").Range.AutoFilter Field:=3, _
        Criteria1:=RGB(255, 255, 0), Operator:=xlFilterCellColor
            With Selection.Font
                 .Color = -16776961
                 .TintAndShade = 0
            End With
        ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Fabrication_Table").Range.AutoFilter Field:=3

     Range("Fabrication_Table[Fab01_Vision02.PositionReagentStripMaSideAvg]").Select
        ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Fabrication_Table").Range.AutoFilter Field:=4, _
        Criteria1:=RGB(255, 255, 0), Operator:=xlFilterCellColor
            With Selection.Font
                 .Color = -16776961
                 .TintAndShade = 0
            End With
        ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Fabrication_Table").Range.AutoFilter Field:=4

        Range("Fabrication_Table[Fab01_Vision02.MSEdgeToOSStripeAvg]").Select
        ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Fabrication_Table").Range.AutoFilter Field:=5, _
        Criteria1:=RGB(255, 255, 0), Operator:=xlFilterCellColor
            With Selection.Font
                 .Color = -16776961
                 .TintAndShade = 0
            End With
        ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Fabrication_Table").Range.AutoFilter Field:=5

        Range("Fabrication_Table[Fab01_Vision03.SpacerRegistrationToPdMaAvg]").Select
        ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Fabrication_Table").Range.AutoFilter Field:=6, _
        Criteria1:=RGB(255, 255, 0), Operator:=xlFilterCellColor
            With Selection.Font
                 .Color = -16776961
                 .TintAndShade = 0
            End With
        ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Fabrication_Table").Range.AutoFilter Field:=6

        Range("Fabrication_Table[Fab01_Vision03.SpacerRegistrationToPdOpAvg]").Select
        ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Fabrication_Table").Range.AutoFilter Field:=7, _
        Criteria1:=RGB(255, 255, 0), Operator:=xlFilterCellColor
            With Selection.Font
                 .Color = -16776961
                 .TintAndShade = 0
            End With
        ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Fabrication_Table").Range.AutoFilter Field:=7

        Range("Fabrication_Table[Fab01_Vision06.LaminatedCavityWidthMaSideAvg]").Select
        ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Fabrication_Table").Range.AutoFilter Field:=8, _
        Criteria1:=RGB(255, 255, 0), Operator:=xlFilterCellColor
            With Selection.Font
                 .Color = -16776961
                 .TintAndShade = 0
            End With
        ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Fabrication_Table").Range.AutoFilter Field:=8

        Range("Fabrication_Table[Fab01_Vision06.LaminatedCavityWidthOpSideAvg]").Select
        ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Fabrication_Table").Range.AutoFilter Field:=9, _
        Criteria1:=RGB(255, 255, 0), Operator:=xlFilterCellColor
            With Selection.Font
                 .Color = -16776961
                 .TintAndShade = 0
            End With
        ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Fabrication_Table").Range.AutoFilter Field:=9

        Range("Fabrication_Table[Fab02_Vision02.WidthReagentStripMaSideAvg]").Select
        ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Fabrication_Table").Range.AutoFilter Field:=10, _
        Criteria1:=RGB(255, 255, 0), Operator:=xlFilterCellColor
            With Selection.Font
                 .Color = -16776961
                 .TintAndShade = 0
            End With
        ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Fabrication_Table").Range.AutoFilter Field:=10

        Range("Fabrication_Table[Fab02_Vision02.WidthReagentStripOpSideAvg]").Select
        ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Fabrication_Table").Range.AutoFilter Field:=11, _
        Criteria1:=RGB(255, 255, 0), Operator:=xlFilterCellColor
            With Selection.Font
                 .Color = -16776961
                 .TintAndShade = 0
            End With
        ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Fabrication_Table").Range.AutoFilter Field:=11

                Range("Fabrication_Table[Fab02_Vision02.PositionReagentStripMaSideAvg]").Select
        ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Fabrication_Table").Range.AutoFilter Field:=12, _
        Criteria1:=RGB(255, 255, 0), Operator:=xlFilterCellColor
            With Selection.Font
                 .Color = -16776961
                 .TintAndShade = 0
            End With
        ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Fabrication_Table").Range.AutoFilter Field:=12

                Range("Fabrication_Table[Fab02_Vision02.MSEdgeToOSStripeAvg]").Select
        ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Fabrication_Table").Range.AutoFilter Field:=13, _
        Criteria1:=RGB(255, 255, 0), Operator:=xlFilterCellColor
            With Selection.Font
                 .Color = -16776961
                 .TintAndShade = 0
            End With
        ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Fabrication_Table").Range.AutoFilter Field:=13

                Range("Fabrication_Table[Fab02_Vision03.SpacerRegistrationToPdMaAvg]").Select
        ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Fabrication_Table").Range.AutoFilter Field:=14, _
        Criteria1:=RGB(255, 255, 0), Operator:=xlFilterCellColor
            With Selection.Font
                 .Color = -16776961
                 .TintAndShade = 0
            End With
        ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Fabrication_Table").Range.AutoFilter Field:=14

                Range("Fabrication_Table[Fab02_Vision03.SpacerRegistrationToPdOpAvg]").Select
        ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Fabrication_Table").Range.AutoFilter Field:=15, _
        Criteria1:=RGB(255, 255, 0), Operator:=xlFilterCellColor
            With Selection.Font
                 .Color = -16776961
                 .TintAndShade = 0
            End With
        ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Fabrication_Table").Range.AutoFilter Field:=15

                Range("Fabrication_Table[Fab02_Vision06.LaminatedCavityWidthMaSideAvg]").Select
        ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Fabrication_Table").Range.AutoFilter Field:=16, _
        Criteria1:=RGB(255, 255, 0), Operator:=xlFilterCellColor
            With Selection.Font
                 .Color = -16776961
                 .TintAndShade = 0
            End With
        ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Fabrication_Table").Range.AutoFilter Field:=16

                Range("Fabrication_Table[Fab02_Vision06.LaminatedCavityWidthOpSideAvg]").Select
        ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Fabrication_Table").Range.AutoFilter Field:=17, _
        Criteria1:=RGB(255, 255, 0), Operator:=xlFilterCellColor
            With Selection.Font
                 .Color = -16776961
                 .TintAndShade = 0
            End With
        ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Fabrication_Table").Range.AutoFilter Field:=17

'Find red formatted text and replace all with *
    With Application.FindFormat.Font
        .Subscript = False
        .Color = 255
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With

    Cells.Replace What:="", Replacement:="*", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:= _
        xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=True, ReplaceFormat:=False

With Application
.ScreenUpdating = True
.EnableEvents = True
.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End With

End Sub
```

I have edited the code by taking out all of the `.Select` functions and significantly reduced the length.  I also removed the replace function of step 4.  Step 3 now performs that job much faster. As below -

```
Sub FabricationClearConDups()

'This Sub will convert all Consecutive Duplicate values within all columns to an "*"

With Application
     .ScreenUpdating = False
     .EnableEvents = False
     .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
End With

'Set conditional format on first data row (B)
With Range("Fabrication_Table[Fab01_Vision02.WidthReagentStripMaSideAvg]")
     .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=OR(B2=B1,B2=B3)"
     .FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
    With .FormatConditions(1).Interior
         .Color = 65535
    End With
End With

'Copy the conditional formatting over to all columns
Range("Fabrication_Table[Fab01_Vision02.WidthReagentStripMaSideAvg]").Copy
 Range("C2").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
 Range("D2").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
 Range("E2").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
 Range("F2").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
 Range("G2").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
 Range("H2").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
 Range("I2").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
 Range("J2").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
 Range("K2").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
 Range("L2").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
 Range("M2").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
 Range("N2").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
 Range("O2").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
 Range("P2").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
 Range("Q2").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False


'Replace value in all formatted cells with *
    With Range("Fabrication_Table[Fab01_Vision02.WidthReagentStripMaSideAvg]")
         .AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=RGB(255, 255, 0), Operator:=xlFilterCellColor
        With Range("Fabrication_Table[Fab01_Vision02.WidthReagentStripMaSideAvg]")
             .Value = "*"
        End With
    End With
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Fabrication_Table").Range.AutoFilter Field:=2

    With Range("Fabrication_Table[Fab01_Vision02.WidthReagentStripOpSideAvg]")
         .AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:=RGB(255, 255, 0), Operator:=xlFilterCellColor
        With Range("Fabrication_Table[Fab01_Vision02.WidthReagentStripOpSideAvg]")
             .Value = "*"
        End With
    End With
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Fabrication_Table").Range.AutoFilter Field:=3

    With Range("Fabrication_Table[Fab01_Vision02.PositionReagentStripMaSideAvg]")
         .AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:=RGB(255, 255, 0), Operator:=xlFilterCellColor
        With Range("Fabrication_Table[Fab01_Vision02.PositionReagentStripMaSideAvg]")
             .Value = "*"
        End With
    End With
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Fabrication_Table").Range.AutoFilter Field:=4

    With Range("Fabrication_Table[Fab01_Vision02.MSEdgeToOSStripeAvg]")
         .AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:=RGB(255, 255, 0), Operator:=xlFilterCellColor
        With Range("Fabrication_Table[Fab01_Vision02.MSEdgeToOSStripeAvg]")
             .Value = "*"
        End With
    End With
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Fabrication_Table").Range.AutoFilter Field:=5

    With Range("Fabrication_Table[Fab01_Vision03.SpacerRegistrationToPdMaAvg]")
         .AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:=RGB(255, 255, 0), Operator:=xlFilterCellColor
        With Range("Fabrication_Table[Fab01_Vision03.SpacerRegistrationToPdMaAvg]")
             .Value = "*"
        End With
    End With
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Fabrication_Table").Range.AutoFilter Field:=6

    With Range("Fabrication_Table[Fab01_Vision03.SpacerRegistrationToPdOpAvg]")
         .AutoFilter Field:=7, Criteria1:=RGB(255, 255, 0), Operator:=xlFilterCellColor
        With Range("Fabrication_Table[Fab01_Vision03.SpacerRegistrationToPdOpAvg]")
             .Value = "*"
        End With
    End With
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Fabrication_Table").Range.AutoFilter Field:=7

    With Range("Fabrication_Table[Fab01_Vision06.LaminatedCavityWidthMaSideAvg]")
         .AutoFilter Field:=8, Criteria1:=RGB(255, 255, 0), Operator:=xlFilterCellColor
        With Range("Fabrication_Table[Fab01_Vision06.LaminatedCavityWidthMaSideAvg]")
             .Value = "*"
        End With
    End With
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Fabrication_Table").Range.AutoFilter Field:=8

    With Range("Fabrication_Table[Fab01_Vision06.LaminatedCavityWidthOpSideAvg]")
         .AutoFilter Field:=9, Criteria1:=RGB(255, 255, 0), Operator:=xlFilterCellColor
        With Range("Fabrication_Table[Fab01_Vision06.LaminatedCavityWidthOpSideAvg]")
             .Value = "*"
        End With
    End With
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Fabrication_Table").Range.AutoFilter Field:=9

    With Range("Fabrication_Table[Fab02_Vision02.WidthReagentStripMaSideAvg]")
         .AutoFilter Field:=10, Criteria1:=RGB(255, 255, 0), Operator:=xlFilterCellColor
        With Range("Fabrication_Table[Fab02_Vision02.WidthReagentStripMaSideAvg]")
             .Value = "*"
        End With
    End With
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Fabrication_Table").Range.AutoFilter Field:=10

    With Range("Fabrication_Table[Fab02_Vision02.WidthReagentStripOpSideAvg]")
         .AutoFilter Field:=11, Criteria1:=RGB(255, 255, 0), Operator:=xlFilterCellColor
        With Range("Fabrication_Table[Fab02_Vision02.WidthReagentStripOpSideAvg]")
             .Value = "*"
        End With
    End With
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Fabrication_Table").Range.AutoFilter Field:=11

    With Range("Fabrication_Table[Fab02_Vision02.PositionReagentStripMaSideAvg]")
         .AutoFilter Field:=12, Criteria1:=RGB(255, 255, 0), Operator:=xlFilterCellColor
        With Range("Fabrication_Table[Fab02_Vision02.PositionReagentStripMaSideAvg]")
             .Value = "*"
        End With
    End With
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Fabrication_Table").Range.AutoFilter Field:=12

    With Range("Fabrication_Table[Fab02_Vision02.MSEdgeToOSStripeAvg]")
         .AutoFilter Field:=13, Criteria1:=RGB(255, 255, 0), Operator:=xlFilterCellColor
        With Range("Fabrication_Table[Fab02_Vision02.MSEdgeToOSStripeAvg]")
             .Value = "*"
        End With
    End With
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Fabrication_Table").Range.AutoFilter Field:=13

    With Range("Fabrication_Table[Fab02_Vision03.SpacerRegistrationToPdMaAvg]")
         .AutoFilter Field:=14, Criteria1:=RGB(255, 255, 0), Operator:=xlFilterCellColor
        With Range("Fabrication_Table[Fab02_Vision03.SpacerRegistrationToPdMaAvg]")
             .Value = "*"
        End With
    End With
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Fabrication_Table").Range.AutoFilter Field:=14

    With Range("Fabrication_Table[Fab02_Vision03.SpacerRegistrationToPdOpAvg]")
         .AutoFilter Field:=15, Criteria1:=RGB(255, 255, 0), Operator:=xlFilterCellColor
        With Range("Fabrication_Table[Fab02_Vision03.SpacerRegistrationToPdOpAvg]")
             .Value = "*"
        End With
    End With
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Fabrication_Table").Range.AutoFilter Field:=15

    With Range("Fabrication_Table[Fab02_Vision06.LaminatedCavityWidthMaSideAvg]")
         .AutoFilter Field:=16, Criteria1:=RGB(255, 255, 0), Operator:=xlFilterCellColor
        With Range("Fabrication_Table[Fab02_Vision06.LaminatedCavityWidthMaSideAvg]")
             .Value = "*"
        End With
    End With
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Fabrication_Table").Range.AutoFilter Field:=16

    With Range("Fabrication_Table[Fab02_Vision06.LaminatedCavityWidthOpSideAvg]")
        .AutoFilter Field:=17, Criteria1:=RGB(255, 255, 0), Operator:=xlFilterCellColor
        With Range("Fabrication_Table[Fab02_Vision06.LaminatedCavityWidthOpSideAvg]")
             .Value = "*"
        End With
    End With
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Fabrication_Table").Range.AutoFilter Field:=17

With Application
.ScreenUpdating = True
.EnableEvents = True
.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End With

End Sub
```

As you can see, it is still very lengthy, but it works a lot quicker than before.

I have just two questions, listed in order of importance -

1. I would like to call this macro (plus another similar one) in my main macro, but can't get it to work.

Here is what I tried -

```
'Call subs for replacing Consecutive Duplicates
With Destwb
Worksheets("Fabrication").Activate
FabricationClearConDups
Worksheets("Kinematics").Activate
KinematicsClearConDups
End With
```

But then I get the following error - "Run-time error '1004 MS Excel cannot find any data to replace.  Check if your search criteria are defined correctly...etc"

Debugging highlights this line -

```
Range("Fabrication_Table[Fab01_Vision02.WidthReagentStripMaSideAvg]").Select
```

I've tried a few different ways to call it out but can't get it to work.  Any ideas?

2. You'll see that in two sections I've just repeated the same lines of code for each column in my table.  Is there any way to use loops to clean things up?  Possibly with generic labels so that it can be applied to a second sheet table with different amount of columns and different headers...

I hope that this edit has improved my question and that my query is much clearer.

Excel 2010, Windows 7.

Comment: Not sure it it works. But try `Range("C2:Q2").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False`.

Comment: That is far too much code to ask for it to be 'optimized'. You need to identify specific, isolated items you have issues with.

Comment: Thank you @Ralph.  Unfortunately that's one technique I've already tried.  It only seems to copy the formatting into the second row rather than the whole column like it does in the original.  I was hoping some kind of loop might work.  Will explore further...
As per answer below, will also work on editting original post and code within.  Hopefully clarify.

Answer (score 2):

I have bad news for you. If you can't understand what the Macro Recorder is doing enough to re-write it yourself, then what you need is to hire somebody to write your macro for you.

Split your function into discrete steps.
Record 1 step.
See what the macro recorder spits out.
Try and understand what it's doing.
Re-write it yourself to be cleaner.
Rinse and repeat (this general process is call refactoring).

E.G. if I record filling a cell in green, I get:

```
Range("A1").Select
With Selection.Interior
    .Pattern = xlSolid
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .Color = 5296274
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .PatternTintAndShade = 0
End With
```

Which I can refactor to:

```
Range("A1").Interior.Color = 5296274 '/ I don't need all those other options
```

Do this enough and

a) your code will be much easier to read and figure out what is going on and
b) you will understand more about how writing VBA code works which will
c) allow you to write code directly yourself and
d) lead to a point where you have code you understand, and can therefore ask a   question saying "I need to do *specific thing* in VBA. How do I do it?"

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Zak
I had intended to work on refactoring (new word for me) all of this.  I got so caught up with things I forgot.  I'll get the code cleaned up and edit my post to clarify what I'd like to do.  
My main concern is over the fact that I have to call out each column one-by-one.  I don't properly understand how to work loops into my code.

Comment: NP. You may want to look at **Cells()** **Rows()** **Columns()**. Which will allow you to loop using numerical values to define the position of your range.

Comment: Thanks again. Already made a big leap in wiping '.Select' out of most of the code, speeding it up.  Will edit post soon.

Comment: Great to hear :) When you do edit your code. Leave the original there and add the new code below. That way, people can see the context for the answers / improvements.